# How does conservation of angular momentum work when a body is rotating on multiple axes?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm trying to understand how momentum is conserved when gymnasts twist mid-air while they are doing a flip. In this post, I will refer to the movement of his feet over his head as "rotation", and the movement of his body on its own axis as "twisting".  Take [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaIUH33athc) video: when he does his layout (the flip at the end of the trampoline) he is twisting on the axis of his body, his left shoulder going over his chest towards his right shoulder, while he rotates on the Y-Z plane (where Y is the vertical axis and Z is the 'depth' axis, parallel to the direction of the trampoline).

However, this twisting around the axis of his own body continues as his body rotates throughout the flip, meaning while the rotation of the flip has a constant angular velocity vector, his twisting is constantly changing as the 'axis' of his body changes.

Can anyone help me understand how this works? How is angular momentum conserved in this case? Does it have anything to do with precession? (which I still don't fully understand).

Comment: While not specifically speaking to gymnasts, the Smarter Every Day video on how [cats land on their feet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtWbpyjJqrU) points out some of the very clever tricks that a not-quite-rigid-body, like a cat or a gymnast, can do while still conserving angular momentum.

Comment: @CortAmmon what is especially interesting about the cat question (I left it out since it did not address the question) is that the cat actually imparts a *net rotation*. In fact, if the cat returns to the same body arrangement after flipping over, in some sense it has "rigid body rotated" itself. It is a great demo of the general caution that "rotations are not vectors" as it would be the equivalent of a stationary system moving its own center of mass without ever having *a moving* center of mass.

Comment: @CortAmmon I've seen that and a few other videos of cats falling and righting themselves mid-air. It's my understanding that the tail is also required to rotate, as the two 'halves' of the cat aren't perfectly parallel and obviously the mid-section of the cat is on a different axis, which means that the body still has a net rotation. If you watch it slowly, the tail goes around in the opposite direction to the body, and I suspect a cat without a tail would not be able to land on its feet.

Answer (score 2):

I have always said that the general rotation problem is misleadingly difficult. Not impossible to understand, but harder than people initially expect.

When studying 3 dimensional rotation, there are two important frames to always consider. These are the non rotating frame (the frame of the room and, roughly speaking, the frame of the camera (over a short time)) and the body frame (the frame according to the gymnast's own senses, a frame affixed to his body).

It is important to remember that angular momentum is conserved in the non rotating frame, since it is a Newton's law consequence and so true in inertial frames of reference.

As a general matter, the rotational form of Newton's law is

$$
\vec{L} = I \vec{\omega}
$$

and

$$
\vec{\tau} = \frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}
$$

which you probably know to some extent. However, be very careful as to what it means. First, the equation can be applied to points other than the center of mass, but it is a bit messier so I suggest we skip that for your question. Then, In the above equation, $\vec{L}$ is the angular momentum about the mass center, $\vec{\tau}$ the total torque calculated about the mass center, and $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity vector of the body about the center of mass. The factor $I$, then is the [inertia tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor).

In the linear Newton's law, the proportionality factor (the mass) is a scalar. While people have some sense of there being "three" such numbers for rotation (the rotational inertia), there are actually *nine* because it is a full matrix (although the matrix is symmetric so there are only 6 degrees of freedom).

We therefore have an equation relating one vector (the angular velocity) to another vector (the angular momentum), by a (symmetric) matrix multiplication. It must be made absolutely clear that $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ need not have the same direction. This is very different than the linear case, where velocity and momentum always are colinear. If the angular momentum is conserved (there is no torque), this means that $\vec{\omega}$ likely changes in magnitude *and direction* as the body undergoes its rotational motion in order to keep $\vec{L}$ constant.

The thing to remember is that as the body rotates, the matrix $I$ changes (according to the fixed frame). If you think about what the formula for the inertia tensor is this  should make sense, because as the body rotates, the mass moves. In general, the integrals I linked to on Wikipedia must change.

The equation of motion will then be

$$
\tau = \frac{dI}{dt}\vec{\omega}+I\frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt}
$$

It should be apparent that one must know the orientation of the body as a function of time in order to find $I$ and its derivative in the above equation. Thus, the equation of motion for three dimensional rotation is quite a bit more complicated than a lot of people think after learning to calculate the rotation of a wheel on one axis or whatever.

In the case of your gymnast, there is no torque during the jump, so the equation of motion is

$$
\frac{dI}{dt}\vec{\omega}+I\frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} = \vec{0}
$$

Which, in principle, can be solved (but not too much in practice).

As for the gymnast you are asking about, from a coarse perspective, when the gymnast jumps he is doing a back flip (angular momentum vector out his right side) and a pirouette (angular momentum vector down). When he is one quarter of the way turned, the "twist" of the pirouette is difficult to see, because the rotational inertia on that axis is large (it is the rotational inertia of doing a "side flip" while standing). When he gets to half way through the flip (he is upside down), his rotational inertia is smaller, and so the twisting speeds up. It goes away again as he gets to three quarters of the way through the flip.

All this is exacerbated by something that the gymnast can do but a rigid body cannot (and so it is not a part of learing rigid body dynamics of rotation). If you look closely, when the gymnast jumps, his arms are spread out a bit. He does the same thing at landing. When he is upside down, he very consciously pulls his arms inward. This allows for the most spectacular twisting to happen while he is upside down. By pulling in his arms while upside down, his rotational inertia on the vertical axis is made the smallest of any time during the jump. This causes the angular velocity to become large due to angular momentum conservation. It also leads to the effect of his rapid twisting while upside down creating surprise and some mystery as to its origins. In slow motion, you can see the twisting at take off and landing, but it is not as pronounced.

Also, as a practical matter, he could never have jumped with such a rapid rotation rate, but he could jump with a slower rotation rate and more inertia. This is similar to how you can't throw a marble that weighs 1/100 of a shot put at 100 times the speed you throw the shot put (your arm can't move that fast).

I will make note here that the *body frame* (which is attached to the body) can be used. It is simpler in that its inertia tensor does not change with time (for a rigid body, for this gymnast it would change as he moves his arms in and out). However, in the body frame, angular momentum is not conserved, so the equation is a bit different. Since we are not calculating anything here, I will just leave it at that, but you can look it up.

Comment: I know that when he pulls his arms in he lowers his inertia and therefore increases the angular velocity of his twist. However, to me it looks like once his arms are pulled in (about 1/4 of the way through the flip, when he is horizontal), the rate of twisting stays fairly constant throughout the rest of the flip, regardless of his orientation (upside down, sideways, etc). I would have thought that his rotation would almost completely stop when he's sideways, and speed up when he is upside down, but it stays about the same.